# How long is a bar?

Tags: guitar, keyboard, beats, production

i have knowledge in reading tonic solfa notation. 4/4, 6/8 etc. I also have knowledge in music and audio production with the use of computer softwares, e.g FL Studios. I wish to know about the length of a bar. And also, about meaaures. thank you...

Answer (score 2):

The length of a bar isn't measured, musically, in any units like inches or millimetres! And really, musically, not measured in time units like seconds etc.

A bar is a convenient way to split up a tune. Most tunes have a rhythm running through them, which is repetitive. A pattern. We count through, and establish when the pattern repeats. Then we know how a bar must be represented.

Often, we count **1** 2 3 4 **1** 2 3 4. So that song is said to be 'in 4'. We then need to decide how to *subdivide* that bar, and often it's into 4 crotchets. That gives us the bottom number. a little like  fraction - 4/4.

If the count is **1** 2 3 **1** 2 3 then it could be 3/4.

Now to the question - and answer. The speed, or *tempo* is dictated by how slowly or quickly we had to count 1 2 3 4 etc. These days, it's noted as b.p.m., which is beats per minute. So, at 60 bpm for those 4 crotchets in a bar, one bar will last 4 seconds. At 120bpm, it'll be 2 secs. What we *don't* do is use a stopwatch to time a bar - unless we're writing for cartoons, films, and so on!

You ask about *measures*. It's a synonym for bars.

Answer (score 0):

A **bar** and a **measure** refer to the same thing, however, *"measure"* is used more in American English. **The length of a bar depends on the time signature.**

For example, if the time signature was `4/4` then the bar would be 4 crotchets *(quarter notes)* long. However,  if the time signature was `6/8` then the bar would be 6 quavers *(eighth notes)* long.

The duration of the bar (in terms of time), is given by the bpm, such that the time of a bar is `60 * number of beats in a bar / bpm` in seconds. E.g. `100 bpm` in `4/4` would be `2.4` seconds per bar.

**Addendum:** Some musician distinquish a bar as the vertical line found in sheet music and the measure as the segment of time corresponding to a specific number of beats.